# Shopping cart with different product

Tags: database, database-design

I have 2 table with Shoes(id,name,price),Coats(id,name,price).I want to store data in 1 table Shopping cart And order details.if orderdetail(shoppingcartId,productid => how do i knows this id shoes Or coats to show on views).Thanks you

Comment: Just for the sake of it, you need to read up on `Normalization` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization. This will most likely solve your problem with redundancy and give you a good starting point on how to design your data storage.

Answer (score 2):

You have a design flaw. You should combine both `Shoes` and `Coats` in one table: `Products`, probably with a `ProductCategory` indicating it is a `Shoe` or a `Coat`.

If you don't want this, you need to add two id's to your `ShoppingCart` table, one for `Shoes` and one for `Coats`.

Comment: Hi patrick.some time shoes and coats is different type,example coats have one more column color,if i add two id in order detail,it two hard to control about color quatity,please give me new idea

Comment: I gave you two options: either normalization, grouping similar data together and split them when needed, or you add two id fields to your `ShoppingCart` table.